# dply filter with exception

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

So I'm trying to filter out certain things in my dataset.

Here's a really parred down example of my dataset:

```
fish <- data.frame ("order"=c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "e", "e"), 
                "family"= c("r", "s", "t", "r", "y", "y", "y", "u", "y", "u", "y"), 
              "species"=c(7, 8, 9, 6, 5, 4, 3, 10, 1, 11, 2))
```

so I have

```
fish <- fish%>%
  filter(
!(order %in% c("a", "b", "c"))&
!(family %in% c("r","s","t","u"))
)
```

which should remove all orders in a,b,c and all families in , r, s, t, u. Leaving me with

```
order    family    species
d         y         10
e         y         11
```

But the issue is, there are two species that are in families that I am filtering out. So say species 1 is in family "r". I want species 1 to stay in the dataset, while filtering all the rest of family r. So I want the output to look like:

```
order    family    species
d         y         10
e         y         11
d         r         1
e         r         2
```

How can I make sure that when I'm filtering out the groups of family, it keeps these two species?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing that "Scorpaenichthys marmoratus" is the genus-species name of a species that is in the Scorpaenidae-family (and maybe "Ophidiiformes" is the order for "Ophiodon elongatus"?) . You are expecting too much of your audience if that is the case. Most of the readers here don't have a huge background in biologic phylogenetics. You should construct a more generic example that includes defining a `fish` data-object that has all these tree features. Also make it clear whether the double negative construction in the phrase "excludes taking these out" actually means "keep those items".

Comment: Cleanest code (not necessarily shortest) would be to perform second filter(species %in% (c(......)) and combine the two data frames via bind_rows.

Comment: I'm going to wait an hour or two before voting to close this question as unclear, but I'm hoping it gets improved with an edit that clarifies the problems and constructs a full example possibly with inclusion of the output of  `dput(head(fish))`

Comment: Hard to be certain without seeing your data and expected output, but maybe something like: `filter(!(family %in% c("r","s","t","u")) | species %in% 1:2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rbind the results of three separate filters:

```
temp1<-filter(fish,order!=c("a","b","c")&family!=c("r","s","t","u"))

temp2<-filter(fish,family=="r"&species==1)

temp3<-filter(fish,family=="s"&species==2)

fish<-rbind(temp1,temp2,temp3)

rm(temp1,temp2,temp3)
```

Comment: No worries; happy researching!

Answer (score 0):

It would be most natural to have the filtering process mirror your logic --

Filter #1: filter-out undesirable `order` and `family`
Filter #2: filter desirable `family`, `species` pairs

*Note: I had to change your `family`, `species` pair criteria to get matches.*

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# your example data
fish <- tibble ("order"=c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "e", "e"), 
                "family"= c("r", "s", "t", "r", "y", "y", "y", "u", "y", "u", "y"), 
                "species"=c(7, 8, 9, 6, 5, 4, 3, 10, 1, 11, 2))

# put filter criteria in variables
order_filter <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
family_filter <- c('r', 's', 't', 'u')

# Filter 1
df1 <- fish %>%
  filter(!order %in% order_filter,
         !family %in% family_filter)

# Filter 2
df2 <- map_df(.x = list(c('r', 7), c('s', 8)),
              .f = function(x) {fish %>%
                  filter(family == x[1], species == x[2])})

# Combine two data frames created by Filter 1 and Filter 2
df_final <- bind_rows(df1, df2)
print(df_final)

#  A tibble: 4 x 3
#      order family species
#     <chr>  <chr>   <dbl>
# 1     d      y       1
# 2     e      y       2
# 3     a      r       7
# 4     a      s       8
```